# Optional to-many relationships in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm

I'm new to Rails (latest version of 3.2), so forgive me if this is a simple question.

I'm looking to model an artist-song-album relationship. Songs belong to artists, and albums belong to artists as well. Of course, artists can have multiple songs and albums, but every song and album can only belong to one artist. A song can optionally be part of an album, or it can just be a stand-alone song.

It's mostly that last part that's tripping me up. I'm thinking `Artist` should `has_many :songs, through: :albums`, but the direction of the association is confusing me. I'm unsure how to explain the relationship going in the other direction, from the optional `Song` to `Album` relationship, and both `Song` and `Album` to `Artist`.

Can someone help clear this up? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Artist should just have many Songs directly since and Artist can have a Song without an Album. You can still access the Artist's songs through an album via:

```
@artist = Artist.find_by_name("Prince")
@artist.albums.find_by_name("Purple Rain").songs
```

Or directly:

```
@artist.songs.find_by_name("When Doves Cry")
```

And then this could be how they relate in the models:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :songs
  has_many :albums 

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :songs
  belongs_to :artist

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :album
end
```

In the other direction you could do:

```
@song.artist.name = "Prince"
@song.album.name = "Purple Rain"
```